# Image not resizing using CapInsets correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uiimage

I have created a singup button as follows:

```
signupButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(facebookLoginButton.bounds.size.height + 40),300,50)];
signupButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
UIImage *signupButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Signup"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
[signupButton setBackgroundImage:signupButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The frame for the button is 300x50 per the above. I have created an image (for Retina devices) as 22(w)x100(h)px.

The image is 22 pixels which includes 10px rounded corners and 2px which are for the repeatable middle section.

I have tried to implement the stretch per the above code with insets as 0,10,0,10 but this does not stretch as expected.

[image]

[image: Actual image]

Can someone explain what the insets should be? Also how to work these out, I cannot find any useful information on how to actually calculate what the insets should be? I have read the Apple documentation on this, but I do not understand how to work these out.

Comment: Set the cap insets to the non-retina image, in this case 0,5,0,5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image has size `22x100` but it is a retina image.

That means the point size is `11x50`.
The insets should be `UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f)`

Comment: Thanks this works, but can you explain where you work out that it would be 5,5,5,5. From an image which is 11x50??

Comment: @StuartM I suppose the corners are 5 points wide and the image is symmetric. Of course, you can increase the `top` and `bottom` components. If the image is not supposed to be resized vertically, you can even go with `(0, 5.0f, 50.0f, 5.0f)`.

Comment: Do you have any information on how to actually work this out? Tips, tricks or tutorials?

Comment: @StuartM It seems obvious to me, please just read the documentation of `resizableImageWithCapInsets`. The concept is the same as [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Create stretchable Image using following code and assign it to respective UIImageView

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Signup"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
```

you need to calculate TopCap and LeftCap of your 9 patch image properly. 
Good luck.